# Suppress warning: unused variable

Tags: c++, c++11, suppress-warnings

Trying to compile my code with the following command:
**g++ Error.cpp -Wall -std=c++0x -o filename**
I get a warning: **Error.cpp:40:30: warning: unused variable ‘ostr’ [-Wunused-variable]**

I've seen that the **-Wall** can be removed to suppress warnings but i don't want to do that. I want to put something in my code to work around it. Only been coding for ~6 months btw.

```
// Error.cpp

#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS 
// Tried using #define _CRT_UNUSED then doing _CRT_UNUSED(ostr) down below
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include "Error.h"

void Error::message(const char* errorMessage) {
    clear();
    m_message = new char[strlen(errorMessage) + 1];
    strcpy(m_message, errorMessage);
}

void Error::operator=(const char* errorMessage) {
    message(errorMessage);
}

Error::operator const char*() const {
    return m_message;
}

Error::operator bool() const {
    return m_message == nullptr;
}

std::ostream& ict::operator<<(ostream& ostr, const Error& E) {
    (void)ostr; // This didn't work, i still get the warning with or without it
    if (!bool(E)) { const char*(ostr); }
    return ostr;
}
```

EDIT: Yes line 40 is the line with the if. For some reason i had thought that `const char*(ostr)` would place `m_message` inside `ostr` and then it could be returned and outputted elsewhere. I didn't recognize that i was just creating a useless variable in the if statement, thought my operator overload would come into play though i'm not 100% sure if i'm using it correctly...

Comment: If you only want to suppress the warning inside the file you can take a look at this part of the documentation: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html

Comment: Which line is line 40? I bet it's the one with the `if`, where you're declaring a local variable `ostr` of type `const char*` (with unnecessary parentheses around its name). What did you want to achieve there?

Comment: The warning is on the line `if (!bool(E)) { const char*(ostr); }`, which declares a variable named `ostr` that hides the `ostr` that is the function argument.    Can you explain what you intend that statement to actually achieve ??  .... because, odds are, it is not achieving it.

Comment: FYI, we keep a list of [good C++ books](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1782465) here on SO; you might want to take a look at one.

Comment: Compiler errors and warnings tell you what line they originate on.  Actually including this information in your actual question, and paying attention to it, is important when diagnosing C++ errors and warnings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [this live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3f1e67f4d94bd257) shows, the problem is not the function parameter `ostr`: that one is used by the return statement.

The problem is the local variable `ostr` of type `const char *` which you're declaring inside the `if`:

```
if (!bool(E)) { const char*(ostr); }
```

The parentheses are legal, but redundant: that line is equivalent to this:

```
if (!bool(E)) { const char *ostr; }
```

You're declaring a local variable (which happens to hide the function parameter), and not using it for anything.

If you want to stream the message from `E` into `ostr`, you'll have to do this:

```
if (!bool(E)) { ostr << static_cast<const char*>(E); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to do the following?

```
std::ostream& ict::operator<<(ostream& ostr, const Error& E) {
    if (!bool(E)) { ostr << E.m_message; }
    return ostr;
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what i am trying to do, however, that function is global and m_message isn't accessible by it.

Comment: @JC_Darko Which we can't know because you didn't include the definition of the `Error` class in your question...

Comment: @Angew I do show that the operator overload is part of the ict namespace and not part of the Error class. I figured that was enough information at the time but I guess you can't assume the member is private or public...

Comment: Make the operator a 'friend' of Error.